# Grails link with params and confirmation

Tags: grails, gsp

Hi I want to make a delete link to some action on controller. My link looks like this:

```
<td>
     <g:link action="delete" params="[branchID:branch.id]" onclick="'Are you sure?'">
         <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
     </g:link>
</td>
```

I want to make user confirm his action `onclick="'Are you sure?'"`. I checked documentation, but I did not find anything useful. It does not have to be `<g:link`, I would be happy for any solution. I have `<g:each` and I want to perform classic update and delete action on every object in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this. For your wish i have written inside g:each

```
   <g:each in="${instance}" var="it">     
      <td><g:link action="delete" params="[branchID:${it.id}]" onclick="return confirm('${message(code: 'default.button.delete.confirm.message', default: 'Are you sure?')}');"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></g:link></td>
   </g:each>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<g:form url="[resource:yourInstance, action:'delete']" method="DELETE">
    <fieldset class="buttons">
    <g:actionSubmit class="delete" action="delete" value="${message(code: 'default.button.delete.label', default: 'Delete')}" onclick="return confirm('${message(code: 'default.button.delete.confirm.message', default: 'Are you sure?')}');" />
    </fieldset>
</g:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
<td>
    <g:link action="delete" params="[branchID:branch.id]"
        onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
    </g:link>
</td>
```

That is not related to Grails. [`onclick`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) is an HTML based click event handler which will work best in your scenario.